# After find and replace of embedded word doc in Excel, changes is saved in the embedded word doc

Tags: excel, vba, replace, ms-word

I'm building a code that will use a template (a Word doc embedded in Excel) and will find and replace certain words in the template using the inputs from Excel. I have successfully coded the opening of the template, find and replace in the template.

But after that, when I check the embedded Word doc in Excel, the replaced words were saved. I don't want to override the contents of the template but every time I run my code, it automatically saves the changes made during the find and replace. I just want it to find and replace, then save a copy to my local folder.

I'm using late binding as there is a limitation in the version of Excel that our team is using.

I don't know if the function of the below code is the one causing the changes to be saved in the embedded Word doc.

```
.Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
```

Here is the my full code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WDApp.Visible = True

Set WDDoc = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Template_112225")
WDDoc.Verb Verb:=xlOpen

WDApp.Selection.WholeStory

Call SplitCell

Call Find("<Part Num>", Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(8, 4).Value)
Call Find("<Dataset>", Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(7, 3).Value)
Call Find("<Letter>", Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(8, 5).Value)

Set WDDoc = Nothing
Set WDApp = Nothing
Set Rng = Nothing

End Sub

Sub Find(Find_Value As String, New_Value As String)
With WDApp.Selection.Find
    .Text = Find_Value
    .Replacement.Text = New_Value
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub

Sub SplitCell()
Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim NumberLetter As Variant

txt = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(8, 3).Value

NumberLetter = Split(txt, "/")

For i = 0 To UBound(NumberLetter)
    Cells(8, i + 4).Value = NumberLetter(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Also is it possible to have a code that will make the Save As dialog box appear? So the user can have a choice on where to save the modified copy.